# Syntax for passing tables to call read() JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, karate

What's the syntax for passing a table like as a parameter to an external JavaScript function with the return value stored in a variable?

```
* table user
| UserId | UserType    | UserRoles        |
| 123    | 'Regional'  | { Role : Ninja } |
```

I'm thinking `* def uid = call read('base64-encoder.js') { user }` where the function is defined as

```
function(uid) {
  var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
  var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(uid.bytes);
}
```

But this gives a:

> ParserException: Unexpected End of File position 7: null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for passing the karate table to an external JavaScript function would in this case be

```
* def uid = call read('base64-encoder.js') user
```

just adding a space for the function parameter.

JavaScript just doesn't know how to handle the list item it gets. So for this function not to fail on type checks, the table row first has to be cast to a string like this:

```
* string me = user[0]
* def uid = call read('base64-encoder.js') me
```

This way the java won't choke on the table and you'll get well-formed JSON strings out of the encoded string:

```
function(uid) {
  var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
  var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(uid.bytes);
  return encoded;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save a JavaScript object in your database table, you can convert the JavaScript value to JSON. JSON content is a string that you can easy save it to. Example:

```
  // Convert to JSON
  var jsonDatas = JSON.stringify(yourDatas);

  // Convert to a JavaScript value
  var javascriptDatas = JSON.parse(jsonDatas);
```

It works, but I don't suggest saving JSON content in the database.

Comment: No, I'm looking to pass a KarateDSL table to a javascript function.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry about that. I real don't know Java. Your question get a tab `javascript` but I think it is a Java's question. You could add the tab `java`, it is better to help you get a solution.

Comment: Its probably ok with the Karate tag. Karate is based on CucumberJVM but its really a beast of its own :)